# Try to connect Action with Reducer but get Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Friends, I have a problem with the connection between `Action` and `Reducer` when trying to send data that come back from the `API` I get **dispatch, not a function** and when trying to `console.log(action.type)` I get `@@redux/INITw.y.u.w.s.a` are any help, and thanks very much

Store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware , compose } from 'redux'
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import combineReducers from './Reducers/index';

const enhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
let store = createStore(combineReducers,enhancer(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)))

export default store;
```

Action

```
import { READ_USER_DATA } from './../Types';

export const fetchUser = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            dispatch({
                type: READ_USER_DATA,
                data: data
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
import { READ_USER_DATA } from './../Types';

const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case READ_USER_DATA:
            return { ...state,userInfo: action.data  }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default userReducer;
```

combine Reducers

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import userReducer from './UserReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
})
```

connect - Code in component-

```
export default connect((state) => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        userInfo: state.user.userInfo
    }
},{ fetchUser })(Home)
```

Comment: how are you calling `fetchUser `?

Comment: Also, are you aware that you are writing a very outdated (pre 2019) style of Redux here? Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer logic, createStore, combineReducers or connect any more. It's also 1/4 of the code. You might be following a very outdated tutorial. I'd highly recommend following the official tutorial instead: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: I am using the useEffect `    useEffect(() => (
        fetchUser()
    ), [])`

Comment: I will change to the new one after solving the error, and what do you think, can I change it now and the problem will be fixed, or it is preferable that I solve the problem before changing to the new version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using the useEffect  `useEffect(() => ( fetchUser() ), [])`

For one, you have to use `{}`, not `()` in your `useEffect`.
Also, you need to call `props.fetchUser`, not `fetchUser` directly when you are using the legacy `connect` function. You should generally not use connect in function components, it is a legacy api to support legacy class components.

So it would look like

```js
useEffect(() => { props.fetchUser() }, [])
```

But it should even be

```js
const userInfo = useSelector(state => state.user.userInfo)
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => { dispatch(fetchUser()) }, [])
```

without using `connect` at all.

Comment: I am using destructuring in props

Comment: That destructuring might have a conflict in some way with the import of the same name. It's a common cause of confusion - but if you don't use connect any more that will all be gone anyways.

Comment: I will keep this information in mind and I will update to Redux toolkit Thank you